# How do I change php.ini value for URL in apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I want to disable output_buffering for a single URL pattern: `/script/*`, how do I do this in apache configuration? I'm using mod_rewrite, so the actual directory doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google, your friend: http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php

My guess (untested):

```
<Location /script/>
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_value output_buffering 0
</IfModule>
</Location>
```